# Не корректно работает TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

Приветствую.
В общем решил добавить визуальный редактор tinymce на свой сайт, но возникло несколько проблем:

1. Всплывающим окнам для вставки ссылок, картинок и т.д. задается стиль сайта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

собственно все едет.

2. Данные с формы передаются со второй попытки, форма на аяксе.
3. Не полностью переведен на русский язык
4. Как убрать этот блок [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инициализирую вот так:

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  theme: 'modern',
  language: 'ru_RU',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
  image_advtab: true
 });
</script>
```

Каким образом можно избавиться от всех этих проблем?

Comment: 4 пункт поборол этим menubar: false

Comment: Визуальная проблема в стиле

input:not([type="submit"]),textarea{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #3e454c;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .35s ease;
      transition: border-color .35s ease;
}

input:not([type="submit"]):focus,textarea:focus{
  border-color: #ff680d;
}